# Rstudio - plots not showing and plots menu grayed out

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, rstudio

I'm using Rstudio Version 1.0.136.  I'm trying to plot some data and when I execute the code nothing shows up in the 'Plot' pane and the 'Plots' drop down menu is grayed out.  Any suggestions?

EDIT:

```
> dev.off()
null device 
          1 

> dev.cur()
null device 
          1
```

I tried restarting R and then ran this code and got this error message:

```
> library(ggplot2);qplot(mpg, hp, data = mtcars)
Warning message:
R graphics engine version 12 is not supported by this version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed.
```

[image]

Comment: what does `dev.off()` return?

Comment: @NateDay - see edit

Comment: well, it was worth a shot :) the only time I have similar issues is when another graphics device is open and the output is being sent there. Looks like the stable R Studio release is up to 1.0.153, is upgrading to the newest version an option? not sure if that will fix anything...

Comment: `dev.cur()` will show your current graphics device. Mine returns "RStudioGD 2"

Comment: @NateDay - same as `dev.off()`

Comment: and when you plot something like `library(ggplot2);qplot(mpg, hp, data = mtcars)` what happens?

Comment: @NateDay - code runs without error but no plotting.

Comment: Standard windows solution (even if you aren't using win): restart RStudio?

Comment: What version of R are you using? Workaround is to use `x11()` until you can update rstudio